# How to see the Deleted browsing history?

Tags: firefox

I have deleted browsing history in Firefox.Is there any way to see the visited sites ?

I have tried Run->regedit->HKEY_CURRENT_USER->Software->Microsoft-Windows->Explorer->userassist->Count->

In those I saw REG_BINARY files , Is there any way to decrypt and see those visited sites.

I m using windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox it is permanently deleted when you delete the history. `The index.dat file is used by IE and not by Firefox.Firefox uses a SQLite database file named places.sqlite to store the history and the bookmarks.` You would need to restore an older copy of this `places.sqlite` file to recover the deleted history.

You can try to restore a previous version of the places.sqlite file if there is one with a promising date/time stamp.
Make sure to first backup the bookmarks because those will be restored as well.

- `Right-click: Properties > Previous Versions`
- [Previous-versions-of-files-frequently-asked-questions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Previous-versions-of-files-frequently-asked-questions)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response Sunny !! :-)

Comment: Well..you can select this as an ANSWER and can UPVOTE too to make it more visible as a right answer for other users. :)